# Return statement that calls a function that returns void in a function that returns void

Tags: c++, return-value

When playing with functions return values, the following code, compiles and works in g++. There is a method that returns void, which calls in a return statement another function that returns void. My question is why do g++ allow this kind of behavior?

```
#include <iostream> 


void Foo()
{
    std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
}

void Boo()
{
    return ( Foo() );
}


int main()  
{
    Boo();

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but it's probably to make it easier to make generic templates. It's also not dangerous since it do match the promised signatures. Check this out for an even more surprising return value: https://godbolt.org/z/W23OhA

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- your guess is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return), when calling `return expression;`:

> The expression is optional in functions whose return type is (possibly cv-qualified) void, and disallowed in constructors and in destructors.

Later, they note:

> In a function returning void, the return statement with expression can be used, if the expression type is void.

`return` can have an expression for a void function as long as the expression is also void, which is what you've done. This could be useful in templates, where the return type of the function may be unknown at the time of writing your function.

Answer (score 1):

`void` is a type that can be used interchangeably with other types in certain circumstances. Your example would make perfect sense if `Boo` and `Foo` returned `int`; why should changing the type be a special exception to otherwise correct semantics?

`return (Foo())` is essentially saying "return nothing," which is, in fact, `Boo`'s stated return type. You'll find that

```cpp
void bar() {
    return void();
}
```

compiles just fine.