# Value initialization of temporary void object in return statement

Tags: c++, templates, return, language-lawyer, void

If I am not mistaken, it is allowed to write `return void()` in function templates to avoid unnecessary specializations and overloads for `void` type.

At the same time, a similar syntax `return void{}` is not recognized by Clang:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() { return T(); }

template<typename T>
T bar() { return T{}; }

int main() {
    // ok everywhere
    foo<void>();

    // error in Clang
    bar<void>();
}
```

Clang 16 prints the error:

```
error: illegal initializer type 'void'
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6o89reK3G

In [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), I have not found the answer: both `T()` and `T{}` should behave the same for not aggregate types. And there are no special comments about `void` type.

Is it just a Clang bug, or on the contrary it is the only compiler strictly following the standard?

Comment: I think the bit about `T()` and `T{}` behaving the same when initializing an object is a red herring. `void` is an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Void_type), there is no such thing as a `void` object, so whatever `void()` is doing it's not initializing one. Suspect the answer has to do with what exactly is governing the validity of `return void()`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981609/return-statement-that-calls-a-function-that-returns-void-in-a-function-that-retu

Comment: Looks like a clang bug/missing feature.  Until C++20, only `T()` was allowed when `T` was `void`.  C++20 allowed using `{}` and it has the same behavior so clang should accept it.

Comment: `void` object? wut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [CWG2351](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2351.html), which is evidently not yet implemented in Clang.

`void()` and `void{}` are equivalent.